# jQuery script not working

Tags: jquery

I was learning jQuery basics. Below is a simple alert box, but it won't work. Please help me.
 I have a  with `id="btn1"`

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() 
{$("#btn1").click(function()
{
alert("55");
}}
));
</script>
```

Please tell me what is wrong with the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have mismatched curly braces and parenthesis. You should write:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btn1").click(function() {
            alert("55");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Include jQuery.js file and refer that file in your code.

```
<script src="path to your jquery file" type="text/javascript"></script>   


$(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        alert("55");
    });
});
```